# Create File Explorer for PDF, Text and Image in Android

Tags: android, file

I am new in android development and I just want to know how to do a customized file explorer that will only display pdf, text and image files.

I tried this example but I dont know how to filter the files that can be displayed :(

[Android File Explore](https://github.com/mburman/Android-File-Explore)

Is there a way to display and select only the files mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [@Smitted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372100/4325604).

Create the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

You can set the MIME types for the intent:

```
intent.SetType("application/pdf");
```

and add additional MIME types:

```
String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "text/*"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```

and start the activity:

```
StartActivityForResult(intent, FIND_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the files in the accept() of new FilenameFilter().